# Function to read selective columns by providing column position POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Sample data in excel file, here first row is header.

```
Demo1           Demo2           Demo3           Demo4           Demo5           Demo6
DummyText1      DummyText2      DummyText3      DummyText4      DummyText5      DummyText6
DummyText11     DummyText21     DummyText31     DummyText41     DummyText51     DummyText61
```

**Below code to include selective column is working fine,however to another column, again I have to add cell1.getColumnIndex() in if condition and so on. :**

```
for (Cell cell1 : row) {
    if (cell1.getColumnIndex() != 1 && cell1.getColumnIndex() != 3) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

**So I created below function to skipCells()**; however it is not working as expected.

```
for (Cell cell : row) {
    skipCells(cell,1,3,6) // this should read only column 1,3 and 6, but it is not working.
    String result = getCellData(xssfWorkbook, cell);
    System.out.println(result);
}

static void skipCells(Cell cell,int ...cellPosition)
{
    for (int i: cellPosition) {
        if (cell.getColumnIndex() != i) {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just iterating over the cells and you do nothing at all, change skipCells to

```
static void skipCells(Cell cell,int ...cellPosition) {
    for (int i: cellPosition) {
        if (cell.getColumnIndex() == i) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Or just create a list of the columns you want to read and check if the column in the list or not.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 6);
for (Cell cell : row) {
    if (list.contains(cell.getColumnIndex())) {
        String result = getCellData(xssfWorkbook, cell);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: second conditions works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while (rows.hasNext())
    {
    int colNumber = 0;
        row=(HSSFRow) rows.next();
        Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

        while (cells.hasNext())
        {colNumber++;
            cell=(HSSFCell) cells.next();

            if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
            {
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" ");
            }
            else if(cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
            {
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
            }
            else
            {
                //U Can Handel Boolean, Formula, Errors
            }



             switch(colNumber){
                                        case 1:
                                            singleRecord.setXX1(cellValue);
                                            break;
                                        case 2:
                                            singleRecord.setXX2(cellValue);
                                            break;
                                        case 3:
                                            singleRecord.setXX3(cellValue);
                                            break;
                                        case 4:
                                            singleRecord.setXX4(cellValue);
                                            break;
                                        case 5:
                                            singleRecord.setXX5(cellValue);
                                            break;
                                        case 6:
                                            singleRecord.setXX6(cellValue);
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            System.out.println("--> Invalid column");
                            }   





        }
        System.out.println();
    }
     /////////////////////////////////////
     create bean class and add getter/setter properties inside switch case 
     you can later add this object to LinkList also and process as you wish
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Prasad, in case of having more than 6 column, again I have to add case. which I don't want.

Comment: pass the HSSFRow to some function and try some logical hooks/crooks you will achieve,  because rest is just brain-storming you are going right

Answer (score 0):

Changed the return type of skipCells function to Cell

```
static Cell skipCells(Cell cell, int... cellPosition){
    Cell c = null;
    for (int i: cellPosition) {
        if (cell.getColumnIndex() != i) {
            continue;
        }
        c = cell;
    }
    return c;
}

for (Cell cell : row) {
    Cell readCell = skipCells(cell, 1, 3, 6)
     if(readCell != null ) { // remove null value if any
        System.out.println(getCellData(xssfWorkbook, readCell));               
    }
}
```